# Android Studio, Ctrl+F1 doesn't show more information

Tags: android, android-studio

Today when I used Android Studio, I couldn't see more information when I clicked "more" or pressed Ctrl+F1.

[image: Screenshot]

The Event Log information shows `NullPointerException: null`.

Comment: Post your source code...

Comment: @sasikumar Don't think it would be relevant in this case since it's the IDE causing the issue.

Comment: i think you are trying to return value inside the void method...

Comment: To clarify, when you press Cntrl + F1, it just tells you more about the offending criteria. Not anything specific to your code. Its possible that although it says more, there is no more to show. As that line pretty much sums it up.

Comment: In other places prompted the "more" information,  also the situation, but before it work is normal.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Remove the `return` Statement as the method is having void type of returning value at start
If you need to add return
change the void to something like int, float (as per your need).

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If There Is Some More Message Then It Will Show To You Otherwise Not.And NullPointerException Is Like A Message In The LogCat When having `return` statement with void access modifier

Comment: I think this android studio related, in other cases "more" information, is also the case, not "return" problem

Answer (score 0):

I found this is due to the problems of the Theme plugin, it is just fine after unloading it.